# Any sane way to log iCloud Drive file activity?

Tags: icloud, files.app

I have been trying to use tools like [FileMonitor](https://github.com/objective-see/FileMonitor) which uses Apples Endpoint Security Framework (ESF) to capture filesystem events.

The goal is to track down an elusive bug with 0-byte files (files getting spuriously emptied and losing their data) when they are saved in iCloud Drive. I'm trying to trigger this bug while FileMonitor is running, and I'm seeing some weird behavior where it seems as if iCloud's daemons (`bird` and whatever other daemons run in the background and handle iCloud file sync) are able to modify the filesystem right under the nose of tools like FileMonitor.

Here's a POC script for testing - requires [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) (`brew install jq`)

**poor-mans-fsusage.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logfile="$HOME/Desktop/FileMonitor.log"
re="^$HOME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt"
e_types='[
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_CLONE",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_CREATE",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_FCNTL",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_RENAME",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_SETACL",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_SETATTRLIST",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_SETEXTATTR",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_SETFLAGS",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_SETMODE",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_SETOWNER",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_SETTIME",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_TRUNCATE",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_UNLINK",
"ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE"
]'

echo "% logging started (file: $logfile)" | tee -a "$logfile"
echo "% using regex: $re" | tee -a "$logfile"

sudo /Applications/FileMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMonitor -pretty |
jq --raw-output --unbuffered --argjson e "$e_types" --arg re "$re" '
  select(.event? | IN($e[])) |
  select(.file.destination?|match($re)) |
  [ .event, .file.process.name, .file.destination ] |
  @tsv' |
tee -a "$logfile"
```

Running this script and then creating/updating the `xyzzy.txt` file at the root of iCloud Drive with common tools like Sublime Text, `echo foo >>xyzzy.txt` or `rm xyzzy.txt` produces output like this, which appears normal:

```
$ poor_mans_fsusage.sh
% logging started (file: /Users/luke/Desktop/FileMonitor.log)
% using regex: ^/Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_CREATE sublime_text    /Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  sublime_text    /Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  bash    /Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_UNLINK rm  /Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_CREATE touch   /Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
```

However, if I open this file up on my iPhone (using Files.app) and modify it there, a strange thing happens. No `ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE` events are seen. Yet the file somehow gets updated. It appears that maybe there is some sort of atomic saving going on (temp file saving, moving (renaming) the original, replacing etc. But I can't be sure. Here's a sample of the output:

```
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_RENAME bird    /Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_RENAME bird    /Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_RENAME bird    /Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
```

If I change the filtering to log all `ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE`s, I get a flurry of activity (I de-duped all the log lines below otherwise it would be pages long)

```sh
$ sudo /Applications/FileMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMonitor -pretty |
jq --raw-output --unbuffered --arg re "$re" 'select(.file.destination|test("/dev/")?|not) | select(.event == "ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE") | [ .event, .file.process.name, .file.destination ] | @tsv'
```

output:

```
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  apsd    /Library/Application Support/ApplePushService/aps.db-wal
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  bash    /Users/luke/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/xyzzy.txt
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  bird    /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.bird/etilqs_bac799c714aa93e7
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  bird    /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.bird/etilqs_cfa75a208c505d56
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  bird    /Users/luke/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/db/client.db
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  bird    /Users/luke/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/db/server.db-wal
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  cloudd  /Users/luke/Library/Caches/CloudKit/CloudKitMetadata-wal
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  cloudd  /Users/luke/Library/Caches/CloudKit/com.apple.bird/495ca00354c4d66c9152fd84c120c685b6176ca8/ca7a898f7b8bf12541584d32a8d0f91029e02709/Records/Records.db-wal
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  cloudd  /Users/luke/Library/Caches/CloudKit/com.apple.bird/7630364a2c49fa3d5bca30c7cabe73ffa3543026/9fadf220be21a0ed291ebfea5f836e034473cd93/MMCS/.cs/ChunkStoreDatabase-wal
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nehelper    /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/com.apple.nehelper/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nehelper_7N50R4/com.apple.networkextension.uuidcache.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nehelper    /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/com.apple.nehelper/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nehelper_Mo766E/com.apple.networkextension.uuidcache.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nehelper    /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/com.apple.nehelper/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nehelper_SIpEJN/com.apple.networkextension.uuidcache.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_09S10o/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_7dKm3g/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_aRjy8M/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_FbnZNA/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_kqbSoo/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_LCh16g/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_MW3AZz/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_N0NXqe/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_nwGsY9/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_oWboib/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_ox3b2R/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_pT0Uvb/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_tkdjzX/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_u8bI23/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_v3zyFJ/tasks.plist
ES_EVENT_TYPE_NOTIFY_WRITE  nsurlsessiond   /private/var/folders/h6/l1plwtys2yg1wlzspg7cd_n40000gn/T/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_nsurlsessiond_xE8v1x/tasks.plist
```

So it looks like a bunch of other helpers are involved in a simple file update on iCloud. I see `nsurlsessiond`, `cloudd`, `nehelper`...

***TL;DR—* is there any sane way to log filesystem activity for files stored on iCloud Drive?**

Comment: Have you looked in the system log?  Mints https://eclecticlight.co/mints-a-multifunction-utility/ may help you extracting the right stuff.

Comment: @Gilby Yes I'm familiar with Howard's (great) utilities. The unified log that Mints interfaces with doesn't contain detailed file activity I'm seeking though.